# C# Multiple Argument Types without Overloading or Generics

Tags: c#, function, types, overloading, dry

What is the best way to handle situations where there are a large number of possible overloads, but the potential arguments don't share a meaningful supertype?

For example, consider the situation below. Writing out every overloaded variation of Outer() is repetitive, but I don't see a way to use generics here, since the possible input types don't share any meaningful supertype that would work for Inner().

```
private int Inner(int a) { /*do something*/ }
private int Inner(string a) { /*do something*/ }
private int Inner(string[] a) { /*do something*/ }

public int Outer(int a, int b)
{
    Inner(a) + Inner(b);
}

public int Outer(int a, string b)
{
    Inner(a) + Inner(b);
}

public int Outer(int a, string[] b)
{
    Inner(a) + Inner(b);
}

public int Outer(string a, int b)
{
    Inner(a) + Inner(b);
}

// et cetera...
```

Comment: Are the objects in question sometimes or always primitives?  If not, can you implement a common `interface`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you already have the best solution.
You don't have any duplicate code.
If you are willing to give up compile time checkings you could create 1 public method with 2 arguments of type object.
You will gain a few less one-line methods but you'll introduce many possible points of failure.
***I don't recommend that,stick to your existing solution***

**Update**
Here is an example with only one Outer method

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Outer(1, "s"));
            Console.WriteLine(Outer("1", "s"));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static int FindInner<T>(T value)
        {
            var type = (from x in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(Program)).GetTypes()
                        where x.BaseType.IsGenericType && x.BaseType == typeof(IInnerManager<>).MakeGenericType(value.GetType())
                        select x).Single();

            return ((IInnerManager<T>)Activator.CreateInstance(type)).Inner(value);
        }

        public static int Outer<T1, T2>(T1 a, T2 b) { return FindInner(a) + FindInner(b); }
    }

    public abstract class IInnerManager<T> { public abstract int Inner(T t); }

    public class InnerInt : IInnerManager<int> { public override int Inner(int t) { return 1; } }

    public class InnerString : IInnerManager<string> { public override int Inner(string t) { return 2; } }

    public class InnerStringArray : IInnerManager<string[]> { public override int Inner(string[] t) { return 3; } }
}
```

Comment: Inner(a) + Inner(b); seems to be duplicated a lot. What would be ideal is to have 1 public method with 2 arguments, and do compile time checking that the arguments are of any of the valid input types (int, string, or string[] in this case.) I do agree that if this is not possible, it's better to have multiple methods than to just have inputs of type "object."

Answer (score 0):

Is Inner(a) + Inner(a) a typo?  Should be Inner(a) + Inner(b)?

That being said it depends what you are trying to have the method do.

You can either concatenate, two integers, add two strings, contatenate a string and an int, add an int to a array of ascii chars, and an array of strings only complicates the question.

An array of strings however may rule out the situation if you want all the strings concatenated together as well.

Comment: Yeah, it was a typo, thank you for pointing that out. As for what the functions do, I was trying to keep it irrelevant to keep the problem more generic. void functions probably would have been better for this example.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this:

```
public class AggregatedResult<T>
{
    private readonly T _value;

    public AggregatedResult(T value)
    {
        this._value = value;
    }

    pulbic T Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this._value;
        }
    }

    public static implicit operator T(AggregatedResult<T> item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(item));

        return item.Value;
    }
}


public class MyAggregatedResult : AggegatedResult<Int32>
{   
    public MyAggregatedResult(Int32 value) : : base(value)
    {

    }

    public MyAggregatedResult WithInner(int a) { /*do something*/ return new MyAggregatedResult(this.Value + 1); }
    public MyAggregatedResult WithInner(string a) { /*do something*/ return new MyAggregatedResult(this.Value + 2); }
    public MyAggregatedResult WithInner(string[] a) { /*do something*/ return new MyAggregatedResult(this.Value + 3);}
}
```

...

```
var value = new MyAggregatedResult(100);
Console.WriteLine(value.WithInner("").WithInner(new String[0]).Value);
```

It is easily extensible and provides a handy [fluent interface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface).

---

#### If you require the same, but for `void` methods

There is not much to change actually:

```
public class ActionAggregate
{
    private readonly ActionAggregate _parent;
    private readonly Action _action;

    public ActionAggregate()
    {        }

    public ActionAggregate(Action action, ActionAggregate parent)
    {
        if (action == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(action));
        if (parent == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(paramName: nameof(parent));
        this._action = action;
        this._parent = parent;
    }

    public void Invoke()
    {
        var ancestorsAndSelfFromTheTop = this.GetSelfAndAncestors().Reverse();
        foreach (var item in ancestorsAndSelfFromTheTop)
        {
            if (item._action != null)
                item._action();
        }
    }

    private IEnumerable<ActionAggregate> GetSelfAndAncestors()
    {
        var cur = this;
        do
        {
            yield return cur;
            cur = cur._parent;
        }
        while (cur != null);
    }
}


public class MyActionAggregate : ActionAggregate
{
    public MyActionAggregate()
    {        }

    public MyActionAggregate(Action action, ActionAggregate parent) : base(action, parent)
    {        }

    public MyActionAggregate With(Int32 value)
    {
        return new MyActionAggregate(
            action: () =>
                Console.WriteLine($"There was an int value of '{value}'"),
            parent: this);
    }

    public MyActionAggregate With(String value)
    {
        return new MyActionAggregate(
            action: () =>
                Console.WriteLine($"There was a string value of '{value}'"),
            parent: this);
    }

    public MyActionAggregate With(String[] value)
    {
        return new MyActionAggregate(
            action: () =>
                Console.WriteLine($"There was a string[] value of '{String.Join(", ", value)}'"),
            parent: this);
    }
}
```

...

```
public class BusinessObject
{
    public MyActionAggregate GetActionRoot()
    {
        return new MyActionAggregate();
    }
}
```

...

```
var obj = new BusinessObject();
obj
    .GetActionRoot()
    .With(123)
    .With("line")
    .With(new[] { "1", "2", "3" })
    .With(321)
    .Invoke();
```

Comment: I like this a lot for the example I posted. Unfortunately it doesn't work directly for my use case, which is my fault for not coming up with an example that reflected my use case accurately enough / not just posting my actual use case. I think the case where Inner and Outer are of return type void instead of int (and obviously Outer doesn't concatenate or result of its Inner calls) would be closer to my use case.